# HTTP response connection reset?

Tags: c++, sockets, http, tcp

I'm writing up a simple web server that implements select components of the http 1.1 protocol and thus far I have a tcp server that serves a static web page to all tcp connections it receives. I feel like there might be a race condition or some other event happening that I'm not aware of.

Here's the essence of the code in question:

```
char hello[] =
    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
    // "Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT\r\n"
    // "Content-Length: 131\r\n"
    // "Connection: close\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    "<html>\n"
    "<head>\n"
    "  <title>An Example Page</title>\n"
    "</head>\n"
    "<body>\n"
    "  Hello World, this is a very simple HTML document.\n"
    "</body>\n"
    "</html>\n";

while(true) {
    addrlen = sizeof(peer);
    sockd2 = ::accept(_sockd, (sockaddr*)&peer, &addrlen);
    if (sockd2 == -1) {
        perror("Wrong connection");
        continue;
    }
    write(sockd2, hello, sizeof(hello));
    // close(sockd2);
}
```

I'm using Google Chrome to connect to localhost:8080 and as is above, the page loads just fine.

If I uncomment the `close` call and `Connection: close` line, the page won't load and instead the developer console reads `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

If I do the above but also uncomment one of the other http header lines, it loads.

What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no 'race condition' here. This is a ***network error.***

The problem is that you're not reading the request *and* not terminating the response correctly.

When the browser writes to a connection that you have already closed, your end issues a TCP RST, which is 'connection reset'.

Read the request. And you must either close the socket or send a content-length header.

You need to read the HTTP 1.1 RFC. It isn't as trivial as you seem to think.

Comment: I didn't read the entire RFC, but read what I thought were the relevant sections: `4. HTTP Message`, `5. Request`, `6. Response`, and `8. Connections`. I'm not really sure what you meant by terminating the response correctly, but I'm now thinking the race condition I'm experiencing is related to not reading the connection _before_ sending the response.

Comment: What I mean is either closing the connection or sending a content-length header (or using chunked encoding). In HTTP 1.1 it is mandatory to delimit the response in one of these ways.